# How to load a saved argparser and overwrite the current one?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

During training my model, I save some training arguments in argparser, something like:

```
torch.save({'iteration': iter,
            'model': model.state_dict(),
            'voc': voc,
            'args': args
            }, 'path')))
```

I was wondering how could I load the saved `args` and (more importantly) overwrite the current `args`? For example，

```
from conf import args
train_args = torch.load(args.path)['args']
args = train_args
```

However, the above codes are ineffective. How could I overwrite the variables in  `args` with the corresponding ones in `train_args`?

Comment: What do you mean by ineffective? Is is throwing an error or the output is not as expected?

Comment: @VishnuDasu It threw an error, "args" is used before assignment. (I updated my question)

Comment: What does this have to do with the python `argparse` module?

Comment: @hpaulj Cause I want to update values of variables in current argparse?

Comment: `pdytorch' Argparser is different from python `argparse`.